# How do I dynamically set headers on a CSV export?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, export-to-csv

We have a PHP based website that generates a CSV export based on a selection of Markdown files. We can select a month's worth of files and export them that way.

What we are trying to achieve is crafting CSV headers in the following manner:

- Includes every header dynamically across all markdown files
- Includes the headers in the same order every month, if possible

A couple of simple examples of markdown files would be

File 1:

```
b: 'value'
c: 'value'
d: 'value'
```

File 2:

```
a: 'value'
b: 'value'
d: 'value'
```

File 3:

```
a: 'value'
c: 'value'
d: 'value'
```

Exporting these to a CSV, I was hoping the headers would be 
a | b | c | d

Since it would, somehow, figure out on the fly that

- File 1. c is always after b, d is always after c
- File 2. a is always before b, d is always after b
- File 3. a is always before c (already the case now), c is before d

Maybe I'm overcomplicating that part of it.

I apologize in advance if I didn't spell this out clearly. I researched `array_unique` and `array_merge` but I'm not sure if either of those would help me get towards my goal here.

The existing function is this:

```
    /**
     * Handle the request if requesting a group is exported to CSV
     */
    public function exportGroupToCsv($year=null,$month=null)
    {
        /** @var Uri $uri */
        $uri      = $this->grav['uri'];
        $segments = $uri->paths();

        $typePath = $this->getTypePath($segments[2]);

        if (!is_dir($typePath)) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('No data found', 404);
        }

        $headers = [];
        $rows    = [];

        /** @var \SplFileInfo $file */
        foreach (new \FilesystemIterator($typePath) as $file) {


            $thisyear = substr($file->getFilename(), 2,2);
            $thismonth = substr($file->getFilename(), 4,2);
            $thisdate = substr($file->getFilename(), 6,2);
            $thishour = substr($file->getFilename(), 9,2);
            $thisminute = substr($file->getFilename(), 11,2);
            $thissecond = substr($file->getFilename(), 13,2);

            if(!$year || ($thisyear == $year && $thismonth == $month)){
                $record = Yaml::parse(File::instance($file->getPathname())->content());

                if (empty($headers)) {
                    $headers = array_merge(['Date'], array_keys($record));
                }

                $sortedRow = [];

                foreach ($headers as $key) {
                    if($key == 'Date'){
                        $sortedRow[$key] = $thismonth."/".$thisdate."/".$thisyear." ".$thishour.":".$thisminute.":".$thissecond;
                    }else{
                        if(array_key_exists($key, $record)){
                            $sortedRow[$key] = $record[$key];
                        }else{
                            $sortedRow[$key] = '';
                        }
                    }
                }

                $rows[] = $sortedRow;
            }

        }

        // Output headers so that the file is downloaded rather than displayed
        header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$segments[2].'.csv');

        // Create a file pointer connected to the output stream
        $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

        // Output the column headings
        fputcsv($output, $headers);

        // Output the values
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            fputcsv($output, array_values($row));
        }

        fclose($output);

        exit;
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: You've done a good job isolating the problem, but your question would be much easier to answer if you eliminated a lot of the irrelevant portions of your code snippet to get to the heart of the matter. See [mcve]. The problem itself seems to be a graph problem solvable with a [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting).

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your letters in an array, you can use the `min` and `max` functions on letters just as well as numbers. Likewise comparison and incrementation!

```
<?php
$letters = str_split("abdh");
$min = min($letters);
$max = max($letters);
for ($i = $min; $i <= $max; $i++) {
    echo $i;
}
```

Output:

```
abcdefgh
```

<sup><sub>(Deciding whether this is sheer lunacy, or a fantastic PHP feature is left as an exercise for the reader.)</sub></sup>

Comment: Note for your file 1 example, you don't have an "a" header. If you always want to start at "a" you can simply use that value.